# post request with xml as data is giving error 415

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests

#data is set to true inside xml tag enable, Not sure why it is showing just true while posting the question
data = '<enable>true</enable>'


response = requests.put('http://10.59.131.51:80/rest/config/running/dot1x/enable', data=data, auth=('admin', 'password'))

print response

response = requests.put('http://10.59.131.51:80/rest/config/running/dot1x/enable', data=data, auth=('admin', 'password'),headers={'Content-type':'application/xml'})

print response
```

Answer (score 0):

the error meaning that the content type sent and the data are differents kind of. The HTTP Code **415** says *Unsupported Media Type*.

Why happened that? Is because in your request you are sending content type = application/xml and the data=True, a boolean type. Only change True by an valid XML (according to yours requeriments).

Acoording to documentation (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/), the **data** argument is the place where you configure the document to send to the server, in this case need be an XML.